# How to associate route table in that Availability zone with multiple subnet using the terraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, terraform0.12+

Recently I have started exploring terraform. My requirement is to associate all the subnet in that availability zone.

```
resource "aws_subnet" "main" {
count = "${length(data.aws_availability_zones.azs.names)}"   
vpc_id     = "${aws_vpc.example.cidr_block}"              
cidr_block = "${cidrsubnet(aws_vpc.example.cidr_block, 8 , count.index)}"         
availability_zone = "${data.aws_availability_zones.azs.names[count.index]}"             
}
resource "aws_route_table_association" "public_rtable" {                                    
   subnet_id      = "${aws_subnet.main.*.vpc_id[count.index]}"  
   route_table_id = "${aws_route_table.rtable.vpc_id}"                                        
 }
resource "aws_route_table" "rtable" {
   vpc_id = aws_vpc.example.id
   route {                                                   
       cidr_block = "0.0.0.0/0"                               
       gateway_id = aws_internet_gateway.igw.vpc_id            
        }
  }
```

Error message I am getting

```
 line 22, in resource "aws_route_table_association" "public_rtable":
│   22:   subnet_id      = "${aws_subnet.main.*.vpc_id[count.index]}"
│
│ The "count" object can only be used in "module", "resource", and "data" blocks, and only when the "count" argument is set.
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `count` in your `aws_route_table_association` as well:

```
resource "aws_route_table_association" "public_rtable" {                                    

   count = "${length(data.aws_availability_zones.azs.names)}"  
   
   subnet_id      = "${aws_subnet.main[count.index].vpc_id}"  
   route_table_id = "${aws_route_table.rtable.vpc_id}"                                        
 }
```